# How to refer React type to a React variable in d.ts file namespace

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I want to declare a namespace called `PluginApi` so users can use this `d.ts` to get code recommendation. In this below code the React is reffering to its `const React` instead of the library React. How do I fix that

```js
declare namespace PluginApi {
    const React: typeof React
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to get around this. The easiest way is to import the React module with a different name:

```
import ReactModule from "react";

declare namespace PluginApi {
  const React: typeof ReactModule;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMCyEAmBXAGyTgDMoIQ4AiKVDKgbgCgmck0CVa4A7FEJAGcw6YgAUCeAObAeAQTDA4AbyZw4aCD0Hxk6GAC44MAJ5gkEEojpZchJMwC%20TIA)

---

Another option is to refer to the imported module via [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) to break out of the [`PluginApi`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) scope.

```
import React from "react";

declare namespace PluginApi {
  const React: typeof globalThis.React;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocgEyTQBsUi4A7FEJAZzHSTgAU6AVwDmwZgEEwwOAG9ycOGgjMO8ZOhgAuODACeYJBExxhdCACMUdACoALYBwB06jBQC%205IA)

Comment: But when using import in a d.ts file then I need to import this file inorder to get code recommendation. My esbuild says Could not resolve "./types/PluginApi". What is edited is remove the `import React from "react";` and use globalThis.React.

```js
declare namespace PluginApi {
  const React: typeof globalThis.React;
}
```